# How to retrieve the data type stored in buffer and pass it to the template?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, asio

I have a problem that when I call async_read I don't know the exact data type which a user sent so I need to retrieve it from the **asio::streambuf** and pass it to the **asio::buffer_cast** template. Also we know that data type is always a tuple where the first element is a string.

Here's a part of the code:

```
private:
tcp::socket             socket_;
asio::streambuf         incoming_;

void readLoop() {
    asio::async_read_until(
        socket_, incoming_, '\n', [&, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, size_t n) {

            if (ec) {
                std::cout << "Client disconnect (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
                return;
            }

            const ???* ptr = asio::buffer_cast<???>(incoming_.data());
            const std::string query = std::get<0>(*ptr);

            .....
            
            incoming_.consume(n);

            readLoop();
        });
}
```

I tried to use the **boost-type-index** module but I it doesn't work the way I need it to.
So I hope you can show me the way how I can do that or at least any hint to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always have to know the type.

You **can** have a list of types (and indeed switch by some kind of (portable!) type id).

The best advice I can give without given context is to look at existing serialization/deserialization techniques.

- use JSON
- use Boost Serialization archives

It is unlikely you "need to `buffer_cast<T>`" because that only works for trivial and standard-layout types (see here for examples [Packing struct in Boost Asio buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868875/packing-struct-in-boost-asio-buffer/22869206#22869206))

there are many examples around on this website (e.g. [Boost beast send json with byte array to client throw websocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66279589/boost-beast-send-json-with-byte-array-to-client-throw-websocket/66283738#66283738), [boost::asio::async_read_until with custom match_char to accept only JSON format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66102070/boostasioasync-read-until-with-custom-match-char-to-accept-only-json-format/66112570#66112570), [Boost.beast : how to return json response only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72233471/boost-beast-how-to-return-json-response-only/72235662#72235662), or for serialization archives: [C++ boost asio : simple server/client with boost:asio::read and boost::asio::write passing a vector of int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74940696/c-boost-asio-simple-server-client-with-boostasioread-and-boostasiowri/74945217#74945217), [sending/receiving a struct in boost::asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47236474/sending-receiving-a-struct-in-boostasio/47243908#47243908) etc., a nice demo with virtual classs hierarchy [Trying to send an derived class through a boos::asio socket using boost::serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66343030/trying-to-send-an-derived-class-through-a-boosasio-socket-using-boostseriali/66350539#66350539)